# Djoser 400 Bad request login users

Tags: python, django, vue.js, axios, djoser

I'm creating an e-commerce app with django rest framework and vue, I'm using djoser.authtoken to handle authentications.

I could successfully create a user with a post request to `/users/` but whenever I try to log in I keep getting `xhr.js:177 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/token/login/ 400 (Bad Request)` in the console and `[22/May/2021 03:06:11] "POST /api/v1/token/login/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68` on the server.

The error messages aren't giving any useful info but here are some of the relevant snippets for my code:

```
# myproject/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('api/v1/', include('product.urls')),
] 


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```
# myproject/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'djoser',

    'product',
]


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```
// axios request

await axios
                .post('/api/v1/token/login/', formData)
                .then(res => {
                    const token = res.data.auth_token

                    this.$store.commit('setToken', token)
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token 
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/cart'
                    this.$router.push(toPath)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    if(err.reponse){
                        for (const property in err.response.data) {
                            this.errors.push(`${property}: ${err.response.data[property]}`)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Could you `console.log` the content of `err.response.data` in your `catch` block ? You should see some meaningful errors there. And can you also show us how `formData` is built ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. But I realized that this happens when you attempt to login with a username and password you set up with django. In that case, this old account has no token assigned to it. When you sign up with a new account at the frontend and use this new account to login, server responds with a 200 success code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).